# "ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not float64" when calculating a series of linear regressions in Python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to analyse the impact of all the components of a composite indicator on the resulting value through a series of linear regression, but getting a value error. Here is the code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
ods8 = pd.read_excel (r'path/ODS_8.xlsx')
ods8 = pd.DataFrame(ods8).fillna(0) #turns MV into 0
ods8ind = ods8.drop('ODS_08', axis=1)
Y = ods8['ODS_08'] #independent variable
def reg_proc(label):
    X = ods8ind[label] #each dependent variable
    regressor = LinearRegression()
    regressor.fit(X, Y)
    regressor.score(X, Y)
    rsquared = regressor.score(X, Y)
    return(rsquared)
rsquared_df = pd.DataFrame({ods8ind: reg_proc(ods8ind) for ind in ods8ind.columns}, 
                       columns = ods8ind.columns)
```

Comment: *Where exactly* does the error pop up? Please update your post to include the full error trace.

Comment: put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question's body.

Comment: you could add example data in code. It seems it needs to convert some data from float to bool.